# How can I connect RocketMQ broker with RocketMQ console to get the details?

Tags: apache, messagebroker, rocketmq

I am a newbie to Apache RocketMQ. I have found that we can use RocketMQ console to get details of RocketMQ message transaction. [see here](https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-externals/tree/master/rocketmq-console)

How do I connect(sync) that console with my locally running RockerMQ broker?

I am using [this documentation](https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/quick-start/) to run a broker and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rocketmq-console is a graphic tool baseed on web(unlike mqadmin base commandline),here is an example about run this application

- modify application config(file path:rocketmq-externals/rocketmq-console/src/main/resources/application.properties),modify name server
- file example

> `

```
server.contextPath=
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=rocketmq-console
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
rocketmq.config.namesrvAddr=127.0.0.1:9876
rocketmq.config.isVIPChannel=false
rocketmq.config.dataPath=/tmp/rocketmq-console/data
rocketmq.config.enableDashBoardCollect=true
```

`

- mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
- java -jar target/rocketmq-console-ng-1.0.0.jar

you should specify your nameserver before package,and then open web browser,and then visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.